# Can Bluetooth be connected with Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I am developing a sensors device that can sense the presence of child in a car if they were left unintentionally by their parent or caretaker. An alert push notification will be sent to the caretaker through mobile application to notify them, once the device detect the presence of child in the car.
I plan to build the sensor device based on multiple sensors and connection. For the connection, I want the application to be connected with the device through bluetooth (BLE) for the first alert. And if the caretaker still ignoring the alert, the second alert notification will be given through internet connection.
I am using Raspberry Pi to connect the sensors, which I am using motion and sound sensor. My question is, Is it possible for me to connect the bluetooth with raspberry pi?

Comment: yes, it is possible since Raspberry Pi has Bluetooth

Comment: So after Bluetooth been connected with Raspberry Pi, it can be operate as usual to connect with android smartphone where by just grant access and open the Bluetooth connection on the smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

As I looked through the internet, I found out that only four out of eight raspberry pi models have bluetooth, including the *Raspberry Pi 3 B+*, *Raspberry Pi Zero WH*,  *Raspberry Pi Zero W*, and the *Raspberry Pi 3*. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009ZIILLI) is a link to a plugable BLE usb, in case you don't have any of the models mentioned. If you want to check if what I said is true, check [this](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/raspberrypi-models-comparison) link out.

Comment: Thank you Macias. My Raspberry Pi is version Raspberry Pi 3 B. So, if the raspberry pi already equiped with Bluetooth connection, therefore no need to connect USB Bluetooth dongle to the Raspberry Pi right?

Comment: Yep. If you have the model on the list mentioned, it should be able to use Bluetooth without having to buy a dongle.

Answer (score 0):

Great Idea,
Thats do able but if you know about Arduino because of the multiple sensors will have the current be high. But if you want to put camera or another similar device Raspberry Pi is the way but keep it simple because of the current limtation as written [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9298/what-is-the-maximum-current-the-gpio-pins-can-output). Keep up with the work, and good luck :) !